# jQuery Plugin - simple feature help

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using [this jQuery Plugin](http://jqueryglobe.com/article/feature-list) to present a sort of "features list" on a website I'm working on.  This plugin is pretty straightforward and effectively does just what [this demo](http://jqueryglobe.com/labs/feature_list/) shows.

There is **one** piece of functionality I would like to implement in this, however.  I would like to be able to put a "previous" and "next" link in the content area of each tab, to switch to the, well, previous or next set of content.

Can anyone offer some help in what should be done to implement this functionality with this jQuery Plugin?

Thanks so much for any assistance you may be able to offer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `previous/next` links that call [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click) (the equivalent of [`.trigger('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) on the right tab element.

[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/WYZ9L/)

Markup, CSS, and JS are identical to the demo linked in the question except for the following:

#### HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- snip, no changes here -->
    <span id="featureNav">
        <a id="prev">&lt; prev</a>
        |
        <a id="next" href="javascript:;">next &gt;</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#content {
    position: relative;
}

#featureNav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0; 
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#prev').click(function ()
{
    var $current = $('#tabs li a.current'),
        $prev = $current.parent().prev();

    if (!$prev.length)
    {
        $prev = $current.parent().siblings(':last');
    }

    $prev.find('a').click();
});

$('#next').click(function ()
{
    var $current = $('#tabs li a.current'),
        $next = $current.parent().next();

    if (!$next.length)
    {
        $next = $current.parent().siblings(':first');
    }

    $next.find('a').click();
});
```

If you understand how jQuery plugins are written, it should be quite easy to incorporate this code into the plugin. I'm not sure if you wanted a one-off solution, or a change to the plugin itself.

Comment: Wow - fantastic response.  Thank you so much for your help; this is exactly what I was looking for.  One caveat....   what if I wanted these "previous" & "next" links to appear INSIDE the #output content?  Or, for instance, if I wanted to have links inside the content that would reflect the actual title of the previous & next tabs' content (I would manually enter the titles, but want the links to remain inside the #output content).   Thanks so much for your help-

Comment: @Cinch: the placement of the links is defined by the structure of your markup, and the CSS. I recommend playing around with that yourself. Dynamically changing link titles is fancier business that would best be implemented by tweaking the plugin itself - and I'm really not sure that would provide any real UX improvement.